# My webview customhtml background onitemclicklistener

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

Hello I have tryed a lot of tutorials and checked on stackoverflow but I have a problem. The custom html webview don't views automatically you must click on the back button of your android phone and then he views him. 
Can anybody help?

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9e1b32"));

   String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1></body></html>";
   webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

and the listview page changer:

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
      switch (position) 
      {
        case 0:
         Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 1.class);     
         startActivity(newActivity0);

    case 1:
     Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 2.class);     
     startActivity(newActivity1);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now with:
You must add the break; under the startactivity
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,

int position, long id) {
  switch (position) 
  {
    case 0:
     Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 1.class);
     startActivity(newActivity0);
    break;
    case 1:
     Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 2.class);
     startActivity(newActivity1);
     break;

}